# Android Oreo: Is there any way to auto - start the application on mobile reboot?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I am developing an application for a business entity. That application should run in the background in every employees' mobile phone. Employees are mostly salesman. The application basically detects location changes and suggest the salesman where they might visit. A kind of reminder application. It also lets other salesmen see where are their teammates.

Right now I am using a foreground activity and it works fine till the system forcefully doesn't kill the service or the phone doesn't reboot due to manual activity or battery discharge.

Ones the application is closed, as of now, the managers in the firm needs to call salespeople to turn on the application once, as on application start it automatically turn on its foreground service. But this is really an extra burden on the management team which can be automated.

I am ok to have any settings based or code based solution. One solution is to root the phones of salespeople and install some extra utility app or write the code based on root APIs, but this will be too much for this simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe permission [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) was not added properly in the manifest. After adding the permission it worked calmly. In on receive method of the broadcast receiver, I am starting the foreground service.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the best way is to use WorkManager https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/ Yes, it still alpha, but works very good.

From other side, you could work on automating the task "managers in the firm needs to call salespeople to turn on the application once". I mean, an app/backend could automatically call the salesman (with some pre-recorded message) or send SMS to them.

Comment: The problem is that they simply ignore such things. But it worked, till oreo 8.1, for further versions we need to worry as of now. But, I will for sure give the work manager a try.

Comment: @RavinderPayal WorkManager works very well on Android 9.0. WorkManager care about the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED and lot of other stuff. Its very simple to use.

Comment: Seems promising, will learn more about it, thanks again @Alex